# Bash adding whitespace when using mkdir with variable

Tags: linux, bash, mkdir

I have observed that when I create a directory using a variable `myvar=2099-100` `mkdir $myvar && echo "done"`, bash adds a whitespace at the end of the directory name. The issue I have here is that this behavior seems to be very inconsistent.

If I run `mkdir $myvar&& echo "done"` the whitespace disappears.
If I run `mkdir ${myvar} && echo "done"` the whitespace disappears.

The inconsistency lies in the fact that if I create the directory without whitespace at the end once, then I can't reproduce the issue. Running the same command that would create a directory with a whitespace does create it without it at the end.

So there are two questions:
What is the best practice when creating directories using bash. Should variable assignment contain quotes?
What is the correct way of referencing the variable when running mkdir (is it `${var}` notation?)?
Why is bash adding whitespace when running `mkdir $var &&` but not adding them when `mkdir $var` (I guess it has to do with expansion)?
Why after creating directory without a whitespace I can't reproduce creation with a whitespace? Is the expanded variable cached somewhere?

Comment: Not experiencing what you are claiming here. Can you show an actual paste of how it manifest? (Maybe with `-v` for mkdir? ls?) Also have you done anything to `IFS`?

Comment: The best practice is to [double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Usually lack of quoting loses whitespace (if any) rather than adds it, I have no idea what happened in your case. Nevertheless you definitely should double-quote in Bash.

Comment: Another useful link: [*When is double-quoting necessary?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618) Personally I tend to quote even when it's not necessary. It's easier for me to remember one rule that says "always quote" than to analyze if I can get away without quotes.

Comment: If this is in a script file, check the line endings (`cat -A file` and look for "^M" as the end of lines) and use `dos2unix` as required.

Comment: Are you accidentally typing something like a non-breaking space (which *looks* like a normal space, but doesn't act like one) between `$myvar` and `&&` (maybe by holding down shift or something like that)? Try viewing the filename with `ls | LC_ALL=C cat -vet` and see what it looks like; normally, that'll just add a "$" at the end of each line, but if there are other weird characters it'll give an alternate representation of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments where right, the non breaking space was the issue. I may have forgotten to add that I'm running script on a remote server where I'm using heredoc to paste the script (unfortunately this is the workaround, terminal hijacking does not work). I'm copying the text from windows terminal (WSL) and we all know how windows clipboard works these days.

As for why I couldn't reproduce the issue, once the file was modified in vim the correct space character was introduced, I've removed the space copied from the text file.

What I've learned here is to sanitize my input before pasting it to the terminal as that may cause a lot of not so obvious issues.